# Disabling flutter_map package rotation while zooming

Tags: flutter, fluttermap

How to disable map rotation in [flutter_map](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_map) while zooming?

I tried this way:

```
MapOptions(

    interactiveFlags: InteractiveFlag.pinchZoom | InteractiveFlag.drag,
    zoom: 15.0,
  ),
```

But this always disable rotation. I only want to temporarily disable rotation when zooming. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the release of [V6](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_map), you can achieve this via the interactionOptions parameter.

[Releases v6.0.0](https://github.com/fleaflet/flutter_map/releases/tag/v6.0.0)

Here is a code sample for reference:

```
FlutterMap(
  options: MapOptions(
    //...
    interactionOptions: const InteractionOptions(
      enableMultiFingerGestureRace: true,
      flags: InteractiveFlag.doubleTapDragZoom |
          InteractiveFlag.doubleTapZoom |
          InteractiveFlag.drag |
          InteractiveFlag.flingAnimation |
          InteractiveFlag.pinchZoom |
          InteractiveFlag.scrollWheelZoom,
    ),
    // ...
```

Comment: Do I need to do different settings for iOS? It is not working in iphone. Still rotates I've added all mentioned flags.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add this

```
MapOptions(
  enableMultiFingerGestureRace: true,
),
```

Found solution in `flutter_map` issues [here](https://github.com/fleaflet/flutter_map/issues/1396#issuecomment-1325920853).

Answer (score 0):

Add "InteractiveFlag.rotate" inside.

```
MapOptions(

interactiveFlags: InteractiveFlag.pinchZoom | InteractiveFlag.drag | 
InteractiveFlag.rotate,
zoom: 15.0,
),
```